# How to remove the effect of other dimensions?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

I have data of 3 Dimensions. the value of the third dimension is highly correlated with the value of the first two dimensions. I want to remove the effect of the first two dimensions on the third dimension. In short, I want to view the variation of the values in the third dimension excluding the variation of the first two dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Regress the third variable on the first two:
$$x_{3t}=a_0+a_1x_{1t}+a_2x_{2t}+u_t$$

Then use residuals in the main regression:
$$y=b_0+b_1x_{1t}+b_2x_{2t}+b_3u_t+e_t$$

Now, $b_3$ is what you are looking for. Obviously, you can change the first regression to nonlinear to whatever fits the relationship of exogenous variables. You can also play with the main regression, by making it nonlinear or errors multiplicative and so on. It all should fit the physics of the phenomenon